# How do you export an object in a module in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, class, module, module.exports

There is something wrong with the way I understand how to use classes in a Javascript module and export them, or some bad assumption I made about how nodejs works. Please help me understand this better. I wanted to write a module that exposed an object that will "store things safely."  I have a file ("safestore.js") with this in it:

```
class Safestore {
    constructor() {
    console.log("SUCCESS!");
        }
    ... // I defined other methods here...
}
exports.safestore = Safestore; // I tried this with `new Safestore` and `new Safestore()` too.
```

I run nodejs on my command line and then:

```
> ss = require('./safestore');
{ safestore: [Function] }
> s = ss.safestore('pwd','./encFile.enc');
ReferenceError: Safestore is not defined...
```

Why is it telling me that Safestore is not defined while executing the safestore function which is defined in the same file where Safestore is, actually defined?

Answer (score 0):

The question does not contain enough information, although there is a clue.  node and nodejs are two different pieces of software, and I was using the wrong one.  I also didn't specify what version of nodejs I ran from my command line.  When I ran it with `node` (instead of `nodejs`) I got errors that made sense and I was able to fix them.

Thanks to @Ethicist for listing the version of Node he used, as this got me to double check all those things.

I just need to remember that node and nodejs each do different things.  Further research shows me that `nodejs` is a symlink to version 8.10.0 of node.js, and `node` is a symlink to the version that I set with nvm.  I solved the problem permanently for myself with `sudo rm /user/bin/nodejs` and I'll remember, if I ever see an error that says nodejs doesn't exist, that it wants the old version of node.js.